# Unable to install bfieldtools & mayavi packages using pip install

Tags: python, pip, vtk, mayavi

In order to install bfieldtools I am required to install several dependencies, one of those is a package called "Mayavi", which in itself requires the installation of two other dependencies VTK & PyQT5.

After installing these two packages, and running `pip install mayavi`, the installer ran smoothly until it reached the stage: `Building wheel for mayavi (setup.py) ...` and at this point it stays for more than 20 minutes (so far).

obviously something is faulty with the installation i just cant tell what it is.

Versions of relevant packages:

Python - 3.9.6, Pip - 21.2.4, PyQt5 - 5.15.4, Vtk - 9.0.3